# Query with subquery using Criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to build a complex query with Criteria.
I created the query in SQL in order to explain you exactly what I want:

```
SELECT ID, DATE
FROM SELLS v
WHERE DATE > (SELECT min(DATE)
            FROM SELLS
            WHERE CODE IN (12345, 12344)
            AND ID = v.ID)
AND DATE>TO_DATE('2015-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
AND DATE<TO_DATE('2016-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY ID, DATE
```

Here is my class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SELLS")
@Getter
public class Sells {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SELL_ID")
    private Integer idSell;

    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "DATE")
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;
}
```

And what I tried in Criteria (start and end are the two dates in the WHERE ('2015-01-01' and '2016-01-01'):

```
    Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(Sells.class);

    List subquery = getSession().createCriteria(Sells.class)
            .add(Restrictions.in("code", {"12345", "12344"}))
            .createAlias("Sells.id", "id")
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.min("date")))
            .list();

    c.add(Restrictions.ge("date", subquery));
    c.add(Restrictions.ge("date", start));
    c.add(Restrictions.le("date", end));
    c.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("date"))
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("id")));
```

I tried to use a DetachedCriteria too but failed.

```
DetachedCriteria query = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Sells.class, "v");
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Sells.class, "bv")
    .add(Restrictions.in("bv.code", codes))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("bv.id", "v.id")
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.min("bv.date")));


query.add(Restrictions.ge("v.date", subquery))
    .add(Restrictions.ge("v.date", start))
    .add(Restrictions.le("v.date", end))
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("v.date"))
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("v.id")));
```

If some one has an idea how to do that it would help me a lot !

EDIT: This looks better but still not working:

```
Criteria query = getSession().createCriteria(Sells.class, "v");
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Sells.class, "bv")
    .add(Restrictions.in("bv.code", codes))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("bv.id", "v.id")
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.min("bv.date")));


query.add(Restrictions.ge("v.date", subquery))
    .add(Restrictions.ge("v.date", start))
    .add(Restrictions.le("v.date", end))
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("v.date"))
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("v.id")));
```

> org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria cannot be cast to java.util.Date

Comment: For those interested, I had no more time to waste so I used HQL !